# Glitching GPUImageAmatorkaFilter with images that are certain dimensions

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

Has anyone seen issues with image sizes when using `GPUImage`'s `GPUImageAmatorkaFilter`?

It seems to be related to multiples of 4 - when the width and height aren't multiples of 4, it glitches the output.

For example, if I try and filter an image with width and height 749, it glitches.
If I scale it to 752 or 744, it works.

The weird thing is, it glitches at 748. Which is multiple of 4, but an un-even multiple (187).

The initial workaround is to do some calculations to make the image smaller, but its a rubbish solution, I'd obviously much prefer to be able to filter any size.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the `forceProcessingAtSize` option? Or if you're using it, have you tried without? And can you elaborate on what "glitches" means?

Comment: @remus I've added examples of the glitch. Where would i add `forceProcessingAtSize` in the `GPUImageAmatorkaFilter` process?

Comment: Ummmm have a look at the docs? Can't remember but there's an example in there.

Comment: seems like the algorithm can only deal with multiples of 4? (i.e. 32 byte aligned?)--the wrapping seems due to assuming the wrong image width. what about padding it with some extra black pixels on the right side to bring your image up to a multiple of 4 width?

Comment: Have you verified that this occurs on an actual device, not just the simulator?

Comment: @BrianShamblen Device too yep

Answer (score 0):

`GPUImageAmatorkaFilter` use `GPUImageLookupFilter` with `lookup_amatorka.png` as lookup texture. This texture is organised as 8x8 quads of 64x64 pixels representing all possible RGB colors. I tested `GPUImageAmatorkaFilter` with image 749*749px and it works (first check your code is [up-to-date](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)). I believe you are using **lookup texture** of wrong size, it **should be 512*512px**.

Comment: The image I am filtering is 749 * 749 (but can be any size...) - the lookup images are all 512 * 512